# Generate random colors per classification label (Python)

Tags: python, classification, cluster-analysis, rgb

The output of my classification is a list of labels per each of the 10 points. For example the list of labels is [1 2 2 4 4 1 3 3 3 3] in which each data point is classified into one of the 4 classes. How would I create a RGB value per classification and create an associated Array of RGB (3 col) values?
Example output:
[[253 0 134], [24 222 128],[24 222 148], [222 111 74] ...]

Comment: Create a list of nice looking colors and then index that list with the class labels.

Comment: Very interesting! How would you recommend the code set up? (Python)

Comment: Post code first

Comment: You could use random values from this dictionary: [`matplotlib.colors.get_named_colors_mapping()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.get_named_colors_mapping.html#matplotlib.colors.get_named_colors_mapping)

Comment: Thanks! How would we use matplotlib.colors.get_named_colors_mapping? (there are no examples on the webpage: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.get_named_colors_mapping.html#matplotlib.colors.get_named_colors_mapping)